# How to make payment done within the App viz Inapp

Tags: iphone

i have done a reader application ,an have 5 books in it each book is loading with the help of five corresponding buttons,but i make these book paid,the user need to pay $.99 for one book,my requirement is i put the 5 button to be disabled for preventing click action,i have another button which just beside each 5 buttons a down lode image like button,when the user tap that button it will go through payment option ,when the payment is done successfully ,i need to enabled the corresponding book reader button.i think you geneous Developrs understand my idea.how to do the payment only option with inapp or urabanairship or any other api which follow the human guidelines of apple payment.i have spend 2 week for the same purpose,i didn't get anything right,i just want the payment only option no need to downlode the book or anything.
how can i active this?
Please help me to this.

Answer (score 0):

Time to take a look at Apple's [In-App purchase programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), or You can also use third party apis [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/docs/inapp_client.html).

Note: you can sell only virtual goods not physical goods.

See WWDC video about In-app purchase programming before implement this feature. Your app might be reject when you do not following right approach.